Computing the address of two ones in a binary string with small circuits
Are there circuits with $o(\log^2 n)$ many gates and $2\log n$ designated output gates computing the following:
INPUT: An input $x=x_1\dots x_n\in\{0,1\}^n$, where for precisely two indices $1\leq i<j\leq n$ we have $x_i=x_j=1$.
OUTPUT: The binary presentation of $i$ and $j$, respectively.
Remark 1. One may assume that the circuits have unbounded fan-in and input gates appear both positively and negatively.
Remark 2. The circuit need not to test if the input contains precisely two ones, so the problem is formulated as a promise problem. However, this is not a restriction, since for fixed $k$ the threshold $k$ function is computable by $O(\log n)$ sized circuits due to: Friedman, Joel. "Constructing $O(n\log n)$ Size Monotone Formulae for the k th Threshold Function of n Boolean Variables." SIAM Journal on Computing 15.3 (1986): 641-654.
A related question is whether there are circuits of size $o(\log^2 n)$ for the following decision problem.
INPUT: An input $x=x_1\dots x_n\in\{0,1\}^n$, where for precisely three indices $1\leq i<j<k\leq n$ we have $x_i=x_j=x_k=1$.
QUESTION: $i+j=k$?
Further remarks.
Let us assume for simplicity that $n$ is a power of $2$. When assuming that there is precisely one index $$ with $_=1$, one can use the OR gates $_{,0}$ and $_{,1}$, where $$ ranges from $1$ to $\log n$ to compute the binary presentation of $i$ as follows: $g_{k,}=\bigvee_{∈[1,]:\text{bit}_k(p)=}x_p$. Here, $\text{bit}_()$ denotes the $$th least significant bit of the binary presentation of $$.
There is an $O(\log^2 n)$ upper bound to first question from above by applying a construction of Friedman. He shows that for every fixed $$ there is an injective function $f$ from $[1,]$ to $[1,]^\ell$ satisfying the following: 1) $$ only depends on $$, (2) $\ell=O(\log n)$, and (3) when applying $f$ to any $k$ distinct elements $i_1,\ldots,i_k$ from $[1,]$ there is a component $j\in[1,\ell]$ in which $f(i_1),\ldots,f(i_k)$ pairwise differ. This component $j$ can then be used as a witness to compute the binary presentation of these $$ distinct elements. This yields an $(\log^2 n)$ sized circuit.
There is an $\Omega(\log n)$ lower bound for deciding whether $i+j=k$ by using a pigeonhole argument. I am not aware of an $\omega(\log n)$ lower bound for this question, nor for the first problem I mentioned.

What "close" positive results do you know?  E.g. do you know whether there are such circuits of size, say, $O(\log^2 n)$?  Do you know anything about the simpler problem of, given $x$ that has just one index $i$ with $x_i=1$, computing the binary representation of $i$?  Do you know any relevant lower bounds?

Yes to all of your questions. Let us assume for simplicity that $n$ is a power of $2$. When assuming that there is precisely one index $i$ with $x_i=1$, one can use the OR gates $g_{k,0}$ and  $g_{k,1}$, where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $\log n$ to compute the binary presentation of $i$: $g_{k,b}=\bigvee_{p\in[1,n]:\text{bit}_k(p)=b} x_p$. Here $\text{bit}_k(p)$ denotes the $k$th least significant bit of the binary presentation of $p$.

There is an $O(\log^2 n)$ upper bound to my problem by applying a construction of Friedman. He shows that for every fixed $k$ there is an injective function from $[1,n]$ to $[1,b]^\ell$ satisfying the following: 1) $b$ only depends on $k$, (2) $\ell=O(\log n)$, and (3) when applying $f$ to any $k$ distinct elements $i_1,\ldots,i_k$ from $[1,n]$ there is a component $j\in[1,\ell]$ in which $f(i_1),\ldots,f(i_k)$ pairwise differ. This component $j$ can then be used as a witness to compute the binary presentation of these $k$ distinct elements. This yields an $O(\log^2 n)$ sized circuit.

I am aware of an $\Omega(\log n)$ lower bound for deciding whether $i+j=k$ by using a pigeonhole argument. I am not aware of an $\omega(\log n)$ lower bound for this question, nor for the first problem I mentioned.

Thanks, that's informative.  Might be worth editing those into the post somehow for background.

I expect that the answer is yes even with $O(k \log n)$ gates and $≤k$ non-zero indices.  $O(k \log n)$ random $≈n/k$-fanin OR gates on the input should suffice to distinguish all possibilities, but the difficulty is doing it pseudorandomly such that the results can be processed efficiently.
